# How to set throughput (RUs) for the whole database in CosmosDB using spring-data-cosmosdb?

Tags: azure, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, azure-cosmosdb

I am using `spring-data-cosmosdb` dependency in my Java project. I want to set throughput of my database via properties, but didn't find such option in existing properties. You can see that this option is presented in the Azure portal:
[image]

Currently I can only set the name of my database with `azure.cosmosdb.database=Core` property.

Edit:

According to the info during container creation, if you set the throughput on the container level, it will charge in addition to database charge rate.
[image]
So whenever I run my spring boot application with `@Document(collection = "Collection1")` and container doesn't exist, it will create a container with default 4000 RUs in addition to database throughput...

**So my question is:** How do I need to create a database with fixed throughput and NOT create containers with any throughput but rather use database-level RU setup?

Comment: you want to set it for the wjole collection?

Comment: yes, I want to set for the whole collection, because setting throughput to the container will increase total RUs used by my database, according to the their info: 
"You can optionally provision dedicated throughput for a container within a database that has throughput provisioned. This dedicated throughput amount will not be shared with other containers in the database and does not count towards the throughput you provisioned for the database. This throughput amount will be billed in addition to the throughput amount you provisioned at the database level."

Comment: I'm confused now, collection and container are the same

Comment: Sorry, I meant database. Edited the post.

Answer (score 2):

I had a quick look at the SDK code. Currently there seems to be no way of setting RUs for the database using SpringBoot+Spring-Data-Cosmos.

The 4000 RUs you are seeing for the container you created is the default value. 
You can set the RUs for an individual container with the following annotation.

```
@Document(collection = "collection1", ru="1000")
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can achieve the same with the following code,

```
 // Java Sync SDK implementation for creating and the replacing the throughput of a Database
DatabaseOfferReplace databaseLevelSyncImplementation = new DatabaseOfferReplace();
databaseLevelSyncImplementation.createSharedThroughputDatabase();
databaseLevelSyncImplementation.executeOfferReplace();
```

Here is a [sample](https://github.com/abinav2307/offerReplace-cosmosdb-javasdk/blob/635a6abbc9e8292bcd3c09a8b1fb4d116bcf0886/src/main/java/com/cosmosdb/ninjas/offerReplace/main/Main.java)

Comment: How can I do it with spring-boot?